# Multiple queries in prisma graphql resolver

Tags: graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

Following this example here:

https://github.com/prisma/prisma-examples/blob/latest/javascript/graphql-sdl-first/src/schema.js

Let's say I have a mutation where I want to update multiple users by passing their ids and emails accordingly. I know the updateMany would probably be the most suitable option, but since different users would have different values, not sure how to pass that without calling multiple resolvers separately. Something like this:

```
updateUsers: (_parent, args, context) => {
        return context.prisma.user.updateMany({
            where: {
                id: { in: args.userIds },
            },
             data: {
                email: ??? <--- use args.emails here
            }   
        })
}
```

or should I just run multiple mutations:

```
updateUsers: async (_parent, args, context) => {
        try {
           args.emails.forEach(email => {
              const user = await context.prisma.user.update({
              where: {
                id: { in: args.userIds },
              },
              data: {
                email: args.email
               }   
              })
           return user;
           }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
}
```

not sure if the last example would even work because of multiple return statements, since all the resolvers have a return statement, how can I run multiple queries/mutations?

Answer (score 0):

`updateMany` allows you to bulk update all rows matching certain conditions with the same data. It does not help you in this case.

You could loop over an array of users to update id and email of each of them. Your approach will not work however, as you seem to have two arrays (a list of user IDs and a list of email addresses). However, instead of fixing your code I'd suggest to change the GraphQL interface you've defined.

Option 1) is close to what you did. You keep a bulk mutation `updateUsers`, but instead of two lists (a list of user IDs and a list of email addresses), it should accept a list of users, each of them having an user ID and an email address.
To improve performance you could use `Promise.all` and not wait for each update to happen, before starting the next one.

Option 2) is the preferable. Instead of a bulk mutation `updateUsers`, I would create a mutation `updateUser` that updates only one user. If client wants to update multiple users in the same request, they can! A single GraphQL request can contain multiple mutations.